# mqtt message parsing problem in a node.js

Tags: node.js, json, parsing

I try to extract the state of a switch from a mqtt message I get when the switch toggles.
The mqtt message I get is:

> {"src":"shellyplus1-08b61fd9e540","dst":"shellyplus1-08b61fd9e540/events","method":"NotifyStatus","params":{"ts":1711558165.32,"input:0":{"id":0,"state":true}}

I need to know the value of the key "state"
I tried following code

```
let mqtt = require('mqtt');
//Connect to the MQTT Server
let client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost');
client.on("connect",function(){
        client.subscribe("shellyplus1-08b61fd9e540/events/rpc");
        console.log("connected to mqtt Server");
});
//parse Sensor message 
client.on ('message',function(topic,message,packet){
        var msgObject = JSON.parse(message.toString())
        var stringified = JSON.stringify(msgObject,'',2);
//      console.log("topic is "+ topic);
        console.log(stringified.params);        //works
        console.log(stringified.params.ts);     //works
//console.log(stringified.params."input:0");    //SyntaxError: Unexpected string
        });
```

I tried different ways to parse the message.
I can read from the stringified object but only till the key "params" and also I can read "ts" but I have to jump to "input:0" and further to "state". There I get always an error because of the : in the key name.
Or is there a different way to get the value of key "state"?
Thank you in advance
Joerg

Brits answer works but this is only the half way to my target. I need to extract the value of the 'state' and neither a dot notation nor the bracket notation works.
...
console.log(msgObject.params["input:0"].state);
console.log(msgObject.params["input:0"]["state"]);
...
I get always

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Comment: This is really a JSON parsing problem and has nothing to do with MQTT. You could simplify this question considerably by focusing only on the JSON aspect.

Comment: The JSON appears to be invalid (i.e. missing a `}`).

Comment: Ref your edit - retrieving `state` works fine in my example (updated answer). However the data in your question has a few issues (missing brace in JSON, you parse then stringify the JSON for some reason, attempt to access data from the stringified version).

Answer (score 0):

The fact the JSON is being transmitted via MQTT is not really relevant; to access a property with a name that contains special characters you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```
const message = '{"src":"shellyplus1-08b61fd9e540","dst":"shellyplus1-08b61fd9e540/events","method":"NotifyStatus","params":{"ts":1711558165.32,"input:0":{"id":0,"state":true}}}';
var msgObject = JSON.parse(message);
console.log(msgObject.params);        // {ts: 1711558165.32, input:0: {...}}
console.log(msgObject.params.ts);     // 1711558165.32
console.log(msgObject.params["input:0"]);    // {id: 0, state: true}
console.log(msgObject.params["input:0"]["state"]); // true
```